# References on properties of Gaussian mixtures with mean zero?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request, information-theory

I was wondering if there are any papers that study properties of the Gaussian mixture
$\nu$ defined as
$$
\nu(A) = \mathbb{E}_{\sigma \sim \mu}\Big[\mathbb{P}_\sigma(A)\Big],
$$
where above $\mathbb{P}_\sigma$ is the distribution of a Gaussian with mean-zero variance $\sigma^2$.
(Perhaps useful to consider the "finite" case where $\mu$ places mass $\mu_j$ on $\sigma_j$, so that we can write
$
\nu(A) = \sum_{j} \mu_j~N(0, \sigma_j^2). 
$)

I am interested in any references that study properties of this type of Gaussian mixture, such as bounds on information-theoretic divergences between two such mixtures.  Note that the key restriction, as compared to general Gaussian mixtures, is that the mean among all the components is fixed at 0.

Comment: The finite case of this mixture is useful in many data science applications. If you're interested in fitting a Gaussian mixture model to a dataset, here would be a good start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EM_algorithm_and_GMM_model

Comment: A newer algorithm with deeper calculus involved is presented here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.07677.pdf

Comment: The finite case is interesting to me --- but this doesn't specifically address the case of mixtures with known means all being zero?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that constraint. Assuming zero mean, both algorithms are a bit overpowered. If the data do come from a zero-mean mixture, the MLE means computed will be small. But I believe either algorithm could be tweaked to force each mean to 0.